# How to make 'abcd' LIKE CONCAT(field, '%') use the index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I want to get all the rows that are the prefix of 'abcd' in mysql.

This query will get the job done, but it will not using the index of field1.

```
select field1
from table1
where 'abcd' LIKE CONCAT(field1, '%')
```

PS: this query will get `field1='a'` `field1='ab'` `field1='abc'`

Is there a way to get the same query result and use the index?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `where field1 LIKE 'abcd%'`?

Comment: Write `WHERE field1 like 'abcd%'`

Comment: This query will get `field1 = "a"`, it is the opposite of  `WHERE field1 like 'abcd%'`

Comment: Then I'd say the query is too uncommon to use the index. What if you add an `order by field1`?

Comment: SELECT field1 from table where LEFT(field1,4)='abcd';

Comment: *Is there a way to get the same query result and use the index?* `WHERE literal LIKE expresion(column)` can use index noway. The only way for to create a query which uses index is UNION of 4 separate queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't want `field1=''` to match?

Here's a way to get the index to be somewhat useful:

```
WHERE field1 BETWEEN 'a' AND 'abcd'
  AND 'abcd' LIKE 'field1%'
```

To be slightly more maintainable, given that @x is `'abcd`':

```
WHERE field1 BETWEEN LEFT(@x, 1) AND @x
  AND @x LIKE CONCAT(field1, '%')
```

It may be that @variables won't work; in that case, conspire to use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.field1
    FROM ( SELECT 'abcd' AS x ) init
    JOIN table1 
    WHERE field1 BETWEEN LEFT(init.x, 1) AND init.x
      AND init.x LIKE CONCAT(field1, '%')
```

(and that may not be good enough)

A third approach would be to use a Stored Procedure to construct my `WHERE` suggestion with literals, then execute it.